# Are there any XSLT processing command line tools?

Tags: windows, command-line, xslt

I want to change an XML file to a modified XML file via an XSLT file and XSLT processing tool.

For example: `xsltprocess.exe -src a.xml -dest b.xml -xslt c.xslt`

Can anyone assist me?

Comment: If you don't have any particular requirements, you can just google for "xslt command line"

Comment: Xalan, Saxon, msxsl, xsltproc ...

Comment: I found XMLStarlet

Comment: I will point out that I arrived here by googling "command line run xslt"...

Comment: I also find this a very valid question! And - as my predecessor above - arrived here via a search. Beats me why this should not meet guidelines...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are looking for an XSLT processor you can use Saxon: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/

You can see the command line options here: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.1/using-xsl.html

Comment: There is also one from Microsoft (if OP needs Windows): http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21714

Comment: @Ivan From you linke, it looks a bit dated, but there is probably a newer version out there. Saxon will work fine on Windows too though (it just requires Java).

Comment: @Ivan Saxon works on Windows (also). More, is XSLT 2.0 vs XSLT 1.0 (msxsl).

Comment: +1 One of the best things about Saxon is that it's an XSLT 2.0 processor (and an XQuery 1.0 processor). It's also available for .NET

Comment: I know msxml.exe but it is dated i think. MS doesnt support xslt processor anymore??

Comment: @sjuu: Perhaps they don't. Saxon will do the job just fine, also on Windows.

Answer (score 26):

Microsoft has a simple command line tool that wraps their XML Parser - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714.

As @Mathias said though, it only supports XSL 1.0 while Saxon supports XSL 2.0.

To run the convertor you downloaded from the given URL run this command

> msxsl.exe backEnd.xml inspectcode.xslt -o backEnd.html

This will tranform the `xml` file using the `xslt` file into the output file in `html` format

Comment: if I remember well, via .NET you could have XSL 2.0 - I think at https://github.com/Zoomicon/tranXform/tree/master/web/tools/XSLTransform I was supporting it (source code available only in zip there at the moment) - I think the trick was to use Mvp.Xml.dll for that (available in the bin subfolder)

Comment: link is now broken, as of 2021-June

Comment: [new github link](https://zoomicon.github.io/tranXform/tools/XSLTransform/index.html)
looks like MS doesn't support the .exe command line tool anymore, instead [a .js file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762796(v=vs.85))
[MS XML FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757858(v=vs.85))

Answer (score 8):

```
# xsltproc [options] stylesheet file
```

This program is the simplest way to use libxslt.
http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html

Comment: Your example `# ...` indicates that you didn't read the entire question. It's tagged with `windows`. Your Un*x admin command prompt is inappropriate here. The link provided leads to a Gnome site. And the mentioned windows binaries there are far away from "simplest". It's difficult, so I would never recommend this as "simplest".

Comment: I wrote a small wrapper that is compatible with Windows https://github.com/physikerwelt/xstlprocJ

Answer (score 7):

You can use [AltovaXML](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html) XSLT 1.0/2.0 engine (also well-formedness and validity checking). There is free of charge community edition with direct (I mean without Java) command line interface e.g.:

```
AltovaXML.exe -xslt2 stylesheet.xsl -in input.xml -out output.xml
```

Check `AltovaXML.chm` help file for usage.

Comment: Looks like AltovaXML has been discontinued. :(

Comment: Altova now call their XSLT processor RaptorXML.

Comment: There is no more free community version.

Answer (score 3):

ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/

The Win32 directory has a lot of goodies, next to precompiled binaries for use on commandline.

I'm not linking to the directory directly, since the root of the project has a rich set of tools for - good for everyone's flavor of the month :)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of XSLT 1.0 processors available, and a handful of XSLT 2.0 processors, and as far as I know every single one of them runs on Windows and can be called from the command line. If your problem is choosing between them, then you're going to have to tell us more about your requirements and constraints.

Comment: Probably should be a comment. Not sure why this got flagged for review after 6 years though...

Comment: It's a perfectly good answer to a rather poor question. (Haven't people got anything more useful to do with their time?)

Comment: Honestly? Agreed. I usually hit "Looks OK" on these but the age stood out

Answer (score 1):

You can find some XSLT engine wrappers, XSLer and XSLTransform (one in Delphi and one in .NET) with source code at https://github.com/zoomicon/tranXform

Comment: [new github link](https://zoomicon.github.io/tranXform/tools/XSLTransform/index.html)

Comment: indeed, the site from above repo is at https://zoomicon.github.io/tranXform/

Answer (score 0):

[XQSharp](http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/download.htm) includes an XSLT 2.0 command line processor.  See the [Xslt Command Line Reference](http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/doc/2.1/xslt-command-line-reference.htm) documentation for details.

Comment: It only has a trial version. I've downloaded it and it doesn't work. Asks to download another version, lol. Don't recommend this tool