# XSLT performing a many-files-to-one transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt, command-line

Is there a way to use a Microsoft Windows command line tool to read an XSLT file and *several* XML files, and produce a single output file?

(I can write such a tool myself if necessary, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

You can access additional XML documents using the `document()` function, or you can supply them as stylesheet parameters (`xsl:param`).

Many XSLT processors have a Windows command line interface, for example Saxon, xsltproc, and msxsl.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. I prefer to use the [xsltproc command line tool](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html), which is cross-platform, lightweight and fast, but there are [more command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527112/are-there-any-xslt-processing-command-line-tools) available. For processing multiple XML files, use the [`document` function](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/func_document.asp).