# Issue creating a LF output from a CRLF input in an xml file for Excel using xslt

Tags: excel, xml, utf-8, xslt-1.0, special-characters

I have some XML that I want to transform into XML that Excel will open in a table.
But, some of my source data uses the string `&#13;` to denote the CRLF and create a new line.
I understand that Excel only responds to the string `&#10;` which is a LF only, to create a new line within a cell.
I have edited the result file to insert the string `&#10;` and I get the desired effect in Excel, so I know its possible to do this.

I thought it would be simple to use a function like translate to swap the string [CRLF] to [LF]. But, I have had no success so far.

*I'm limited to XSLT 1.0*

Using some simple sample .xml borrowed from W3:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
        <comment>Text on one line</comment>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Still got the blues</title>
        <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1990</year>
        <comment>Text with a break&#13; here (crlf)</comment>
    </cd>
```

We can see that within a `<comment>` the string `&#13;` is used.
In the .xsl itself I've used this:

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <!-- TABLE CONTENTS -->
    <Row>
        <!-- Title -->
        <Cell>
            <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </Data>
        </Cell>
        <!-- Artist -->
        <Cell>
            <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
            </Data>
        </Cell>
        ...
        <!-- Comment -->
        <Cell>
            <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="translate(comment,'&#13;','&#10;')"/>
            </Data>
        </Cell>
    </Row>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The header of my XSL looks like this:

```xml
?xml version="1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

Currently the result is like this:
[image: transformed xml viewed in Notepad++]
[image: transformed xml viewed in Excel]

**EDIT**
Settings in Excel:
[image: Wrap text enabled]

Where a [CRLF] symbol has been used rather than the string `&#10;` which would work in Excel and display the cell with the break inside it. If I edit the result to insert the text string `&#10;` Excel will break the text within the cell in the desired way:

[image: transformed xml in Notepad++]
[image: viewed in Excel]

I'm stuck with XSLT 1.0, am I missing something simple here?

Many thanks in advance.

**edit**
OS is WIN, and I'm using the XML tools plugin in Notepad++ to perform the transform while testing.

I just used some webpage to test another engine:
[image: webpagetransform]
I can see there is a break within the field, but its not the test string `&#10;` and I don't believe that Excel will use it to start a new line within a cell

Comment: You have literal CRLF in the XML, you don't need to insert another `&#10;` too. Have you formatted the column to allow newlines in cells? (You have not because the text overlaps the adjacent cells.)

Comment: I cannot figure out what your question is. Do you know exactly what your input uses to denote a line break? Do note that CRLF is **two** characters, a carriage return (`&#13;`) followed by a line feed (`&#10;`). To transform a CRLF to LF, you only need to remove the CR.

Comment: Many thanks @michael.hor257k and @GSerg
I checked if Wrap Text was enabled in Excel which shows the second line in the cell normally.  The input file only works when `&#10;` is described and not when `&#13;`

So, basically my question is.  "How can I transform the `&#13;` from the input xml data into a `&#10;` for my output (excel) file?

Comment: What you have: `translate(comment,'&#13;','&#10;')` does exactly that. The `disable-output-escaping="yes"` part is not required and can only cause problems.

Comment: thanks @michael.hor257k I just tested removing the `disable-output-escaping="yes"` part and it has no effect.  the `translate` doesn't appear to do what I want.  The result when viewed in Notepad++ shows the [CRLF] symbol and not the text string`&#10;` which is what I'd like to see written to the result file to be used in Excel

Comment: I didn't say the DOE is the cause of the current problem. I said it could cause other problems. In fact, I don't know what causes you current problem. Which XSLT processor are you using? BTW, you should not expect to see the text string `&#10;` at the output; you should see the LF character. This *could* be represented by the `&#10;` entity, but it's not likely.

Comment: I'm using the XML Tools plugin within Notepad++ to process
Do you think Notepad is changing the output file in some way?

Comment: I think it is possible it forces a LF to the Windows standard CRLF.

Comment: @michael.hor257k
I've just edited the original post to show the results with an online processer

Comment: I am afraid you don't understand something very basic: in XML, the `&#10;` character reference is exactly the same thing as the LF character. The processor can choose to output either one (and it will normally choose to output the actual character). A conforming XML parser will read both as the LF character, with no distinction between them.

Comment: I'm not an expert in Char encoding at all! ;p
I would have expected Notepad++ to show just [LF] as the symbol if this character was present in the result though, and I didn't see this

Comment: You should perform one more test: using `<test>A&#10;B</test>` as the input and a stylesheet that does nothing except copy the input, see if the result contains the CR character (i.e. if you get the sequence `41 0d 0a 42`  in the hex dump). If so, you will know that the problem has nothing to do with the transformation itself (or Excel) and is purely due to how your environment serializes the result (possibly there are are some preferences you can change?).

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k I just created a simple .xsl to copy the input and saw this as Hex
`41 0d 0a 42`
So, I think this is probably Notepad++ using my OS to "fix" the EoL operations for me?

Comment: I cannot think of another explanation.

Comment: I'm going to try a different processor, I was recommended IntelliJ IDEA!
But if you know a better option, please let me know

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA is not a processor, it's an IDE (as is Notepad++). I suppose another option is to run the transformation from the command line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527112/are-there-any-xslt-processing-command-line-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the entry for the 1st cell and not the 2nd?

```
<root>
   <cell>this is&#10;a line feed</cell>
   <cell>this is
a line feed</cell>
</root>
```

it may be helpful to look at this

if your data looks like this

```
<data>
    <item>
        <test>A&#13;B</test>
    </item>
</data>
```

this stylesheet produces the output below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="lineFeed">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Root>
            <Cell>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(data/item/test, '&#13;')"/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(data/item/test, '&#13;')"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(data/item/test,'&#13;',$lineFeed)"/>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <xsl:call-template name="convertToLineFeed">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="data/item/test"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </Cell>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="convertToLineFeed">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="before" select="substring-before($string, '&#13;')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$before">
                <xsl:value-of select="$before"/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#10;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:call-template name="convertToLineFeed">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, '&#13;')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which outputs this

```
<Root>
  <Cell>A&#10;B</Cell>
  <Cell>A&amp;B</Cell>
  <Cell>A&#10;B</Cell>
</Root>
```

i.e. note that the 1st line does do what you want the 2nd one doesnt

I don't understand Michael Kay's answer, not because its wrong but because I don't have insight into the workings of the XSLT engine, so the answer is too technical for me.

In my simplistic terms, the 1st line works because its writing the line feed directly to the output, so it sidesteps some of this "normalisation" stuff, the 2nd line the linefeed is encoded in a raw text fragment and gets normalised before its written to the output (something like that).

So I think you CAN do what you want by writing a recursive template to  do what the 1st cell example does, just recursively (I think), I'll do it now.

---

I've now added the recursive solution as line 3.

Comment: just be wary, if there are lots of '&#13' in the input, then it wont scale very well, and can run out of memory (as its recursive).
I'm pretty sure its fine in your use case of < 1000 chars and <50 line feeds

Comment: lets see if any of the others give a more direct mechanism, its one of those ones that if you know the engine inside out, you may be able to do in in a single expression.....I dont

Answer (score 1):

An XML parser will always normalise line endings, so that an actual CRLF sequence in the input is equivalent to an NL (aka LF) character. But if the newlines are written as entity references, for example `&#13;`, this does not happen.

(Note that `&#13;` is CR, not CRLF as you seem to be suggesting.)

If the newline characters bypass normalization in this way, the XSLT processor will treat them as ordinary characters like any other. The serializer (which turns the XSLT result tree back into lexical XML) will turn a CR character into `&#13;` or some equivalent to ensure that it round-trips when re-parsed. But an NL character survives round-tripping so this special treatment is not needed.

You can convert CR characters to LF using `translate(., '&#13;', '&#10;')`.

Converting CRLF to LF is a bit more difficult in XSLT 1.0. If you know that you only have CRLF sequences, and not CR on its own, then you can use `translate(., '&#13;', '')`.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Kay,
I thought I had used `translate(., '&#13;', '&#10;')` in my xsl, but it's not giving me the result I wanted in the output file.
I only wanted to do this swap for one particular node `<comment>` the other EOL operations are fine

Comment: I don't understand your answer, see my clarification, the OP wants an escaped '&#10;' but the (MS) XSLT engine translates this into a proper (?) one.

Comment: I'm afraid the question is so unclear that you may well be right in suggesting that I misunderstood what the OP wants. Reading it again, I'm not at all sure the OP understands the difference between CR, LF, and CRLF, let alone their XML-escaped forms. In fact, my answer wasn't really trying to solve the OP's problem, it was just trying to provide information that might help to reduce their confusion. Probably in vain.

Answer (score 0):

This not (yet?) an answer, but I need the space for some code.

Please run the following test:

**XML**

```
<rows>
    <row>
        <name>no line breaks</name>
        <text>one line only</text>
    </row>
    <row>
        <name>line feed</name>
        <text>first line&#10;second line</text>
    </row>
    <row>
        <name>carriage return</name>
        <text>first line&#13;second line</text>
    </row>
    <row>
        <name>CRLF</name>
        <text>first line&#13;&#10;second line</text>
    </row>
</rows>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#13;', '&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You should see a result that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
    <row>
        <name>no line breaks</name>
        <text>one line only</text>
    </row>
    <row>
        <name>line feed</name>
        <text>first line
second line</text>
    </row>
    <row>
        <name>carriage return</name>
        <text>first line
second line</text>
    </row>
    <row>
        <name>CRLF</name>
        <text>first line

second line</text>
    </row>
</rows>
```

And if you are able to look at the hex dump of the result file, you should see this sequence at the line break of the two middle rows:

```
65 0A 73
```

representing the characters `e, LF, s`. And in the last row it should be:

```
65 0A 0A 73
```

Comment: Using that code ^^ I'm seeing 
`65 0d 0a 73`
for ea instance between the first lin**e** and **s**econd line

Comment: Well, that is not the correct result. It seems like there is an additional step taking place here while serializing the output. But that's just a guess.